# Override focus method for single element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a custom component that needs to play nicely with native blur and focus functions. I am trying to override these functions to provide the functionality I require.

I am able to override the prototype functions like this:

```
$('div#foo').__proto__.focus = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);   
}
```

The problem with that is it overrides the focus function for ALL div's. I only want to override this function on a specific element that is a part of my component.

Here is a fiddle kind of showing the gist of what I want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/5mXVL/3/

Comment: Why are you doing it on proto when you want it on specific div?

Answer (score 1):

How about attaching a new focus event and using `preventDefault` to stop whatever was happening.

```
$('#foo').focus(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // your code...
}
```